# How to solve "cannot get hardware address" error , Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit

Tags: networking, server, 16.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04. When I try to connect to my ISP server(wired) from my terminal, it's gives a error  `cannot get hardware address`.

The error log is-
`2016-07-13 06:09:21 [4354] crclient1.1 Build $Date: 2003/05/01 13:37:30 $
2016-07-13 06:09:21 [4356] ERROR: ioctl() failed. No such device`

I did not get this error, when I was using this same wired internet `Ubuntu 14.04`.

To connect to the internet, I have to login to my ISP's server with a program called `24 online client`

Error message

[image]

My hardware address

[image]

Comment: So no one else never found this problem ?!!!!1

Comment: I did bump into this but it is just that I don't have any solution to this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly download new version of crclient from site and install on ubuntu 16.04

follow the below procedure it works
1) ./crclient -u username -i interfacename

for your problem it is
./crclient -u walid2 -i ens33

2) for logout you have to execute below command
./crclient -l username